# Changing font size based on screen area?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make it so that when the screen area changes the font will too! I have got it to calculate the font size correctly and have checked with breakpoints. However, fontSize does not change appropriately, for example I run my program on 1300x740 and the fontSize is calculated to be 13 however it will not change the font to that size even though the variable FontSize does equal 13, instead the font is much much smaller than 13. I have tried making a temporary variable `Dim fontSize As Integer = 13` and this changed the textbox to the correct size.

Here is my code:

```
Private Function Resizing()
    Dim totalBaseScreenArea As Double = 1936 * 1100
    Dim totalCurrentScreenArea As Double = Me.Width * Me.Height
    Dim value As Double = totalCurrentScreenArea / totalBaseScreenArea
    Dim fontSize As Integer = Math.Ceiling(txtEnterMP.Font.Size * value)
    txtEnterMP.Font = New Font(txtEnterMP.Font.FontFamily, fontSize, txtEnterMP.Font.Style)
End Function
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Your code example (and question) does not state where you are running this code. In what event are you running that code?

Comment: Hello @ThePeter I am running the code in a private function called Resizing(), it is called on Load of the form and at Resize of the form.

Comment: `Dim fontSize As Integer = Math.Ceiling(txtEnterMP.Font.Size * value)` is measuring the font from the control, but then you change it in the next line.  I'm guessing you should use a base font that doesn't change, like `Dim fontSize As Integer = Math.Ceiling(Me.Font.Size * value)`

Answer (score 0):

This solution calculates a new font size based on the size/area of the form. In the designer, add a label called `lblFont` to a blank form and anchor it to all four corners.

In the code behind, add this code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private OriginalFontSize As Single = Me.Font.Size

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call Resizing()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeEnd
        Call Resizing()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Resizing()
        Try
            'Get the screen resolution of your monitor (may not be the monitor the program is running on)
            Dim iWidth As Integer = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
            Dim iHeight As Integer = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height

            'Calculate screen area
            Dim totalBaseScreenArea As Double = iWidth * iHeight
            Dim totalCurrentScreenArea As Double = Me.Width * Me.Height

            'Calculate the new font size
            Dim value As Single = (totalCurrentScreenArea / totalBaseScreenArea) * 30
            Dim NewFontSize As Single = Math.Ceiling(OriginalFontSize * value)

            'Stop the font from being super tiny and hard to read
            If NewFontSize < 8 Then NewFontSize = 8

            'Display the new font size
            Me.Text = "Calculated: " & NewFontSize
            Me.Font = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, NewFontSize, Me.Font.Style)
            lblFont.Text = "The font size of this label is " & NewFontSize
        Catch Exp As Exception
            lblFont.Text = Exp.Message
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```